# Change column data type from boolean to integer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a column called `:active` in one of my database tables (I'm using postgres) that is currently a boolean value, and is defaulted to `true`. I'd like to change this column's type from boolean to integer, so that I can use an enum going forward with this project. I've checked the documentation and some stack overflow answers, but haven't found a solid answer yet. How do I do make this change using migrations? I am using Rails 5, if that makes a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your migration file should look like this

```
def change
    change_column :table_name, :active, :integer
end
```

Also you need to rewrite all the previous records to an integer value which can be done in the same migration file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new migration with:

```
rails g migration change_data_type_for_active
```

Then edit the migration to use `change_column`:

```
class ChangeDataTypeForActive < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    change_column :table_name, :active, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :table_name, :active, :boolean
  end

end
```

Then run the migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

The reason to define `up` and `down` methods is that you can return you database to the previos state with:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same situation, default value was a blocker.

you'll have to remove it first, it won't cause any data inconsistency since it's already set for the existing rows.

In a single migration, I did three steps:

- Had to remove the default value constraint

  ```
    change_column_default(:table_name, :column_name, nil)
  ```
- change the column type, with a case condition where 0 maps to "true" in my ENUM and 1 maps to "false"

  ```
    change_column :table_name, :column_name, :integer, :using => "case when column_name then 0 else 1 end"
  ```
- finally, added a default value for my use case

  ```
    change_column_default(:table_name, :column_name, 1)
  ```